# posting a form while using mpfirewall reports XSS attack

Tags: php, security, xss, firewall

[updated]
I'm using [mpfirewall](https://github.com/miculprogramator/mpfirewall) for my PHP application but when I submit a user form I get XSS attack.
The form contains ckeditor textarea that send its value with tags like `<p>` which triggers xss detection

```
private function _ENTITIES() {
    array_walk_recursive($_GET,get_class($this)."::_callHTMLENTITIES");
    array_walk_recursive($_POST,get_class($this)."::_callHTMLENTITIES");
    array_walk_recursive($_COOKIE,get_class($this)."::_callHTMLENTITIES");
}

private function _callHTMLENTITIES(&$item, $key) {
    $item = htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES,'utf-8');
}

private function _XSS() {
    array_walk_recursive($_GET,get_class($this)."::_callXSS");
    array_walk_recursive($_POST,get_class($this)."::_callXSS");
    array_walk_recursive($_COOKIE,get_class($this)."::_callXSS");
}

private function XSS() {
    array_walk_recursive($_GET,get_class($this)."::_detectXSS");
    array_walk_recursive($_POST,get_class($this)."::_detectXSS");
    array_walk_recursive($_COOKIE,get_class($this)."::_detectXSS");
}

private function _callXSS(&$item, $key) {
    $item = filter_var($item, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}

private function _detectXSS($item, $key) {
    if ($item != strip_tags($item)) {
        $this->write_logs("XSS");
        die("xss attack");
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<form action="" name="myForm" method="post">
<table>       
    <tr>
        <td>Details</td>
        <td><textarea name="desc" class="ckeditor" id="desc" >
</textarea><script type="text/javascript">CKEDITOR.replace('desc')</script></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input name="save" id="save" type="submit" value="Next" /> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am unsure how to fix this.

Comment: If you're allowing HTML to be rendered then it _could_ be an XSS exploit that is being attempted. How are you preventing script code from being rendered when output?

Comment: The firewall script is executed before saving the data in variables. CKeditor sends its content including html tags like <p> then the xss detection is triggered automatically before handling the data

Comment: Sounds like the firewall script is incompatible with what you are doing (saving rich text in your DB). I'd remove the "firewall" but ensure that you are sanitizing HTML on _output_ using a tried and tested library (e.g. Google Caja). A Content Security Policy is also recommended.